# How to add interactive features (line and label) to a D3 line chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to `D3.js` and currently developing a `line chart` for one of my projects. I referred the documentation and example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245) and created my own version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/SKb8W/6/).
Now, I am planning to add two interactive features here:

1. On mouseover in the chart draw a vertical line to the nearest data point.
2. Show a label with X and Y attributes next to this vertical line.

To make this features more clear, please refer this [example](http://c3js.org/samples/simple.html).

Here is what I tried which came from a suggestion:

```
svg.append("g")        // creating new 'group' element
.selectAll('rect')     // adding a rectangle for the label
.selectAll('line');    // adding a line
```

However, the line ans rectangle doesnt show up. I have been Googling a lot but in no vain. What am I missing?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/SKb8W/6/)

Comment: Have you seen [NVD3](http://nvd3.org/)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Thank you for the suggestion but I am restricted to use D3 library only.

Comment: with the .selectAll('rect') and .selectAll('line') you are selecting all the rectangles and lines inside the 'g' element you just created, which is empty. That's why you are not getting those elements to show up.

Comment: [This answer should help you figure out the nearest datapoint based on the mouse position](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21744213/3128209).  [This tutorial should help you figure out how to position an HTML tooltip overtop of your SVG](http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/kFDvH).  But you're also going to need to spend some more time with [d3 tutorials](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials) and building your own simple charts in order to clearly understand how selections work (and don't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//create groups for line and label (and invisible selection area)
var infos = svg.append('g')
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
//move to datapoint location
  .attr('transform',function(d,i){d.x = x(d.date)  ; d.y = 0; return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";});

//create and select line "rectangles" (easier than doing actual lines)
infos.append("rect")
.attr('class','line')
.attr('height', height)
.attr('width', 1)
.attr('opacity',0);

//create and select line "rectangles" (easier than doing actual lines)
infos.append("rect")
.attr('class','area')
.attr('height', height)
//should probably do something to make sure they don't overlap, such as measure distance between neighbours and use that as width
.attr('width', width/data.length/2)
.attr('opacity',0)
//move so that the data point is in the middle
.attr('x',-width/data.length/4)
.on('mouseover', function(){
    g_elem = this.parentNode;
    d3.select(g_elem).selectAll(".line").attr("opacity",1);
})
.on('mouseout', function(){
    g_elem = this.parentNode;
    d3.select(g_elem).selectAll(".line").attr("opacity",0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SKb8W/7/

For labels, here is a useful example: http://jsfiddle.net/WLYUY/5/ (from [D3.js: Position tooltips using element position, not mouse position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256454/d3-js-position-tooltips-using-element-position-not-mouse-position))

And for using mouse coordinates you can do something like:

```
var coordinates = [0, 0];
coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
var x = coordinates[0];
var y = coordinates[1];
```

(from [Mouse position in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770763/mouse-position-in-d3))